# Passing a List of Enum to Spring REST using Get method @QueryParam

Tags: spring, list, enums, get, query-string

I am using Spring and I need to pass a list consisting of enum values using the GET METHOD. Is it possible to use @QueryParam for a List ? If yes, then how and how do we send it through the url.

I used @QueryParam List enumValues and sent data through the url as enumValues=value1&enumVales=value2.

But I get the following error:

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are using JAX-RS annotation `@QueryParam` with spring. Spring is not compliant to JAX-RS framework, they are completely two different MVC frameworks. If you rather use Spring annotation `@RequestParam`, the configuration is simple and it will create list of Enum for you:

> - Your query parameters will look like this: `enumValues=value1&enumVales=value2`
> - Your spring RequestMapping will look like: `@RequestParam(value="enumValues")List<EnumValues> enumValues`

Comment: Glad was able to help.

Comment: Hey..but why does QueryParam works fine with simple String and Integer variables that I am passing through the same link but causing trouble for the list<enum>?

Comment: Spring is not fully compliant with JAX-RS, some of the basic features/annotations may be supported. But its a straight thumb rule, if you are developing using Spring REST/MVC use Spring Annotation & if you are developing following JAX-RS like using Jersey framework, use JAX annotations. With Spring you shouldn't even have `javax.ws.rs` package in your classpath, not required.